# Copycat Chess (Part 2/3)

Tags: story, chess

The mandarin stared bewildered on the chess board after Li Chai [finished his winning move](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30693/15632):

> [image: first game]
>
>  1. d4 d5 2. Qd3 Qd6 3. Qf5 Qf4 4. Qxc8#

But it didn't last for long. He grabbed his queen and repeated Li Chais last move while announcing:

*What kind of mate is that, if I can mate you as well?*

This was of course against the rules, but Li Chai stayed calm and started the second game.

> **How did Li Chai win the second game?**

---

**The rules (same as in part 1):**

- standard chess rules apply, if not stated otherwise
- you play white and your opponent copies all your moves (e.g **1. e4** would be followed by **1. ... e5**)
- you are allowed to make "stupid" moves, your opponent will copy all moves regardless how bad they are
- you are not allowed to make moves which cannot be copied, of course except for the last move winning the game

**New rule:**

- make it impossible for the mandarin to repeat the mating move

The limit for this part is **7 moves**.

Comment: This could also be posted on the **Chess Stack Exchange**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is new for me and I'm not sure but this seems to work:

> [image]
>
>  1. d4 d5
>  2. e4 e5
>  3. d:e5 d:e4
>  4. Bg5 Bg4
>  5. Q:d8#

Comment: @Sleafar, let me guess, now mandarin will eat his pawn with his king?

Comment: [Nope. :)](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30707/copycat-chess-part-3-3)

Comment: Oh, so the last move can be anything (legal)?

Comment: @Anonymous, what do you mean? Last move must be checkmate.

Comment: I mean I thought the last move must be also copied.

Comment: @Anonymous, one of rules: "make it impossible for the mandarin to repeat the mating move".

Comment: Yeah I was confused with that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to use exactly $7$ moves, then:

> > 1. e4, e5. 2. Nf3, Nf6 3. Nxe5, Nxe4 4. d4, d5 5. Qh5, Qh4 6. Bg5, Bg4 7. Qf7#

Comment: Sorry, but the mandarin would simply repeat the move: Qf3. Please read the question carefully, especially the new rule.

Comment: @Sleafar : I suppose the point is that 7...Qxf2 wouldn't be a "counter-mate", because the queen can be taken by White's Qf7.