# Copycat chess is back

Tags: chess

*This puzzle is inspired by and has similar rules to the [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/copycat-chess-part-1-3) [of](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30697/copycat-chess-part-2-3) [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30707/copycat-chess-part-3-3) by Sleafar.*

**Definition.** A *copycat chess opening* is a sequence of moves starting from the conventional starting position, where every move by White (including the last one) is copied by Black identically, resulting in a symmetrical position with respect to the mid-horizontal axis. Every move must be legal, but the last move doesn't have to be checkmate, hence the name *opening* instead of *game*.

> What is the shortest copycat chess opening in which a rook captures another rook?

Comment: Does it need to be symmetrical up to the rook capture or after the rook capture?

Comment: @Brandon_J *every move, including the last one...*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about seven moves each

> 1) p-a4 p-a5
>   2) p-b4 p-b5
>   3) p(b)xp pxp
>   4) p-a6 p-a3
>   5) p-a7 p-a2
>   6) pxN=R pxN=R
>   7) RxR RxR

Comment: Made it viewable here: https://lichess.org/study/CsNAXWW1

Comment: A mix of descriptive and algebraic notation

Comment: @trolley813 That's because I am old-school - originally learned P-KR4 etc.

Comment: @Penguino Here descriptive is even better since you have to write each move only once (e.g. 1. P-QR4 2. P-QKt4 3. KtPxP 4. P-R6 5. P-R7 6. PxKt=R 7. RxR, I probably write it wrong, since in my country DN isn't used at all).

Answer (score 10):

I hope this answer doesn't get sniped...

> It did get sniped, but @penguino had an answer that I built off of: 
>  
>  1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. bxa5 bxa4 4. a6 a3 5. a7 a2 6. axb8=R axb1=R 7. Rbxa8 Rxa1

Explanation:

> We can't have one of white's rooks that's already on the board take one of black's rooks across a file, since that move would not be copyable. Also, it's impossible for the rooks to capture each other along a rank, since that would require the rooks *pass* each other at some point, which  cannot happen as they will mutually block each other each move they make. 
>  
>  The only other way to have a rook takes rook opening would be pawn promotion, whereby the mirrored pawns promote to a rook and then take the already-there rooks. This quickly leads us to the pawns on the a- and b-files (or g- and h-files), and thus, the solution above.

Comment: Yes you did :) +1 though.

Comment: Maybe if I added an explanation...

Comment: Regarding your explanation, it's a tiny bit trickier: why couldn't the capture occur horizontally and hence be possible to copy? (with the 4 rooks involved...)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: for a horizontal rook capture a rook would have to move to the opposite side of the board. This can't be mirrored because the rooks would collide. ie assume no other pieces in the way to move a rook from a1 to a6 is possible but then the opponents rook would need to move from a8 to a3 - impossible due to the rook on a6.

Comment: @Chris True. But PilsNot has edited his answer since then to add this point of explanation.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed the answer had been updated since you asked.

Answer (score 7):

Here’s another way, but on the kingside.

> 1. g4 g5 2. h4 h5 3. gxh5 gxh4 4. h6 h3 5. h7 h2 6. hxg8=R hxg1=R 7. Rhxg1 Rxg8

And while I’m at it, here are the fastest way to do this with all other pieces, minus the kings of course.

Pawns:

> 1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. bxa5 bxa4

Bishops:

> 1. b3 b6 2. Bb2 Bb7 3. g3 g6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. Bxg7 Bxg2

Knights:

> 1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ne5 Ne4 3. Nc6 Nc3 4. Nxb8 Nxb1

Queens:

> 1. b4 b5 2. c4 c5 3. cxb5 cxb4 4. b6 b3 5. b7 b2 6. bxc8=Q bxc1=Q 7. Qdxc1 Qxc8

Now I can say that I have predicted the future! ;¥ ;D

Comment: (+1): Wow, I didn't know there could be variations of this puzzle in the way you have shown!

Comment: Bishops not fastest: 1. b3 b6 2. Ba3 Ba6 3. Bxe7 Bxe2 4. Bxf8 Bxf1.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to make the same puzzle with other pieces. For me the rooks are by far the most interesting because you *have* to find the trick, otherwise it's not possible (fastest or not).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Actually, the same thing applies to queens too.

Comment: @trolley813 well, not exactly the same thing: White rooks can't leave the lower half of the board while Black rooks can't leave the upper half. Queens, however, can move diagonally and therefore reach the opposite half of the board easily. The only reason they can't capture another Queen is that there are only two of them. If there were four like the rooks, then you wouldn't need a promotion.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> 1. h4 h5 
>  2. g4 g5 
>  3. hxg5 hxg4 
>  4. Rxh8...?

Comment: lol nice answer; beat me to it

Comment: No idea if it’s right or not but that’s the first thing I thought of haha @Brandon_J

Comment: I think both of you forgot to read the rules: every move, including the last one... :)

Comment: @Brandon_J this entire puzzling experience has been very meta LOL

Comment: "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" - XKCD

Comment: Seriously, this answer completely misses the point, it's sad to see this many upvotes, people don't read the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's

> 8 moves

[lichess study](https://lichess.org/study/5n9csDIv)

> 1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. axb5 axb4 4. Nc3 Nc6 5. b6 b3 6. b7 b2 7. b8=R b1-R 8. Rxb1 Rxb8

Comment: Think I just sniped you, friend!

Comment: I think both of you forgot to read the rules: every move, including the last one... :)

Comment: Weeeelll, I'm late to the party again @ArnaudMortier

Comment: @Brandon_J I hope you had fun anyway :)