# Chess with symmetric move-square

Tags: chess, checkerboard, knight-moves

Every move in chess involves moving a piece to a square.  Let us call this square the "move-square" for that turn.

In the following, **the *move-square* of the black player must be symmetrical** (over the obvious center-horizontal) **to the move-square by white on that turn.** The requirements may be met with a white move, but *an additional valid move for black must be shown to exist*. This extra move is not included when counting the number of moves taken to reach one of the below conditions.

> What is the shortest sequence (with symmetrical move-squares) resulting in a Rook x Rook capture?
>   Resulting in a Knight x Rook capture?
>   Resulting in Queen x Bishop capture?

Comment: Hi @ArtemLugin, welcome to Puzzling SE! (Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already!) Can you clarify if the same piece has to occupy black's move-square as white's, or can any piece count? For example, would something like 1. e4 e5 2. Be2 Ne2 be acceptable? Or is only Be7 by black possible?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Its doesn't have to be the same piece.  Only the corresponding symmetric square.  Assuming you mean Ne7 not Ne2 yes, thats acceptable

Comment: @RewanDemontay the game ends at the capture, theres no need for the capture to occur twice.  If it ends with a white move, a valid move by black must be shown to exist (in description)

Comment: I can't accept your edit as it contains improper grammar and is inaccurate.  I'm open to suggestions and edits to improve understandability

Comment: I think the question is clear enough, perhaps some terminology can be fixed but at least I can tell what’s being asked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Partial** (will update as I go)

R x R (3rd attempt)

> I got it! **5 moves**:
>  
>  1. a4 a5 2. Ra3 Ra6 3. Rh3 Rh6 4. d3 d6 5. Rxh6 [Apronus link](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_a5_Ra3_Ra6_Rh3_Rh6_d3_d6_Rxh6) 
>  
>  The h3 square is covered by the black bishop. 
>  
>  Note that 5 is the absolute minimum number of moves needed, since it takes at least 3 moves to make the rooks attack each other, and they can’t directly take each other on the 4th move.

R x R (2nd attempt)

> I found a **6 move** solution: 
>  
>  1. a4 a5 2. Ra3 Ra6 3. Rb3 Rb6 4. c3 Nc6 5. Rb5 Nb4 6. cxb4 Rxb5 
>  
>  [Apronus link](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_a5_Ra3_Ra6_Rb3_Rb6_c3_Nc6_Rb5_Nb4_cxb4_Rxb5)

R x R (1st attempt)

> [This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/81497/57742) demonstrates a **7 move** sequence, but since we don’t have to copy each others’ moves, only the squares, we can also do the more interesting 
>  
>  1. a4 a5 2. Ra3 Ra6 3. Rc3 Nc6 4. e4 Ne5 5. Rc5 Nc4 6. c3 Rc6 7. Bxc4 Rxc5 
>  
>  [Apronus link](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_a5_Ra3_Ra6_Rc3_Nc6_e4_Ne5_Rc5_Nc4_c3_Rc6_Bxc4_Rxc5)

Comment: You're on the right track.  There are several ways to get it in 5 moves with white capturing the piece

Comment: The question you linked was the inspiration.  Thought I'd spice it up.  a-Rook takes h-rook looks very interesting as well

Comment: Great job!  Marked as correct

Comment: @ArtemLugin While you're free to Accept whichever answer you think best addresses the puzzle, it's a bit unclear why you would select one that only answers one of the three parts of your question. Did you mean to pick this one?

Comment: @Rubio of the 2 answers, neither solves all 3 questions correctly.  This answer contains the correct solution to the most difficult of the 3, while the other the latter 2.  If that answer is updated I'll consider marking it correct.

Comment: @ArtemLugin Fair enough :)

Answer (score 5):

Under your rules, here are my answers.

Rook X Rook:

> 1. g4 g5 2. h4 h5 3. gxh5 gxh4 4. h6 h3 5. h7 h2 6. hxg8=R hxg1=R 7. Rgxh8

Proof Game:

> [Apronus](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=g4_g5_h4_h5_gxh5_gxh4_h6_h3_h7_h2_hxg8ZR_hxg1ZR_Rgxh8)

Knight X Rook:

> 1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Nh4 Nh5 3. Ng6 Ng3 4. Nxh8

Proof Game:

> [Apronus](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Nh4_Nh5_Ng6_Ng3_Nxh8)

Queen X Bishop:

> 1. e4 e5 2. d4 d5 3. Bg5 Bg4 4. Qxg4

Proof Game:

> [Apronus](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_e5_d4_d5_Bg5_Bg4_Qxg4)

UPDATE: Do you mean improve my Rook X Rook game like this?

> 1. a4 a5 2. Ra3 Ra6 3. Rb3 Rb6 4. Rxb6

Proof Game:

> https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_a5_Ra3_Ra6_Rb3_Rb6_Rxb6

Comment: Oooh, I found one I really like. Looks kind of flashy IMO: 1.e4 e5 2. Qe2 Be7 3. Qb5 Bb4 4. Qxb4

Comment: Great solutions.  RookxRook can be improved

Comment: Should I add another or 2?

Comment: @ArtemLugin generally, if you're going to change the question (by adding questions) simply ask a new question!

Comment: @RewanDemontay not a solution because black doesnt have a valid follow-up move

Comment: The shortest is 5 white moves

Comment: I would upvote your answer for having solutions to all three (even though rook isnt the best solution) but dont have enough rep